# Apache stopped working after update - requests just timeout now - problem with firewalld

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl, apache-virtualhost, certbot

UPDATE:
I tried rolling back the yum update and it did not resolve the problem.  I also tried running the server with only a single virtual host and no SSL and then trying to access site via http.  I still did not work, but the SSL errors went away, so I think I have eliminated SSL as the source of the problem.  I enabled debug level logging and rechecked all logs - nothing helpful.

I stopped firewalld and the sites work again.  OK great, but I should probably fix the firewall.  JSBillings pointed out some issues in his comments regarding the type of container my VPS is in and known issues with firewalld.  I am going to need to look into them more thoroughly.

Recap problem:
Apache runs (shows running if I do systemctl status httpd), but will not serve pages.  Remote requests are not hitting the httpd request logs.  I don't see anything in firewalld log related to my attempts to connect from remote machines.

Here is where it gets interesting:
If I run Links on the same virtual host and point to any one of my domains, I get "Unable to retrieve : SSL error".  If I point links to loopback or server IP, I get one of my virtual hosts, so I disabled that host and tried again.  The result was the next virtual host in alphabetical order.  If I point browser on my desktop to server IP, I get a timeout just like when I try to go to domain name.

I also tried to point Links to http version and it does seem to redirect to https (and then gives same error as above).  I can see the successful Links requests in the logs, but not the unsuccessful ones.

Could this be an issue with my hosts or DNS?  Or is the virtual hosts module broken now?  I feel like I eliminated SSL as the cause, but still see some evidence that it's the issue (the Links error).  Or is this something else entirely?

Keep in mind that everything had worked for months until I did yum update and reboot yesterday (kicking myself for that now).

**Background/config**

I have a VPS running CentOS 7 and Apache 2.4.6 along with PHP and MariaDB.  I use a virtual hosts setup to host 4 small sites, each with a unique domain name.  I will use domain1.com in lieu of my real domain name.
Example virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain1.com
  -other typical settings...
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain1.com
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have directory settings I won't bother listing.

I used Certbot (Letsencrypt) to setup my SSL months ago.  It added virtual hosts files and the redirect in my original host file (above).  I renewed my certs several times since then.

**Everything was working fine until I ran and update and rebooted this afternoon.**

**Here are entries from yum log that have HTTPD, SSL or TLS in them:**

```
Apr 29 13:17:41 Updated: httpd-tools-2.4.6-93.el7.centos.x86_64
Apr 29 13:18:29 Updated: httpd-2.4.6-93.el7.centos.x86_64
Apr 29 13:20:55 Updated: 1:mod_ssl-2.4.6-93.el7.centos.x86_64
Apr 29 13:18:39 Installed: gnutls-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64
```

**SSL ERROR LOG**
(I have substituted my real domain with "domain.com")
(these entries started after the update today)

```
[Wed Apr 29 16:47:40.447536 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 4945] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for domain1.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Apr 29 16:48:26.901356 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 485] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for server.domain1.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

I researched those warnings and I cannot reach a definitive conclusion about what causes them.  However, since they are just warnings, they shouldn't be causing the problem.  Still, it's the only clue I have about the problem.

**HTTPD ERROR LOG**
(I have seen this stuff in the logs prior to update)

```
[Wed Apr 29 16:48:27.061664 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 485] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Apr 29 16:48:32.016207 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 485] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.2.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 29 16:48:32.016265 2020] [core:notice] [pid 485] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Apr 29 17:04:52.428739 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 485] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Wed Apr 29 17:04:53.548204 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 1182] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Apr 29 17:04:53.554485 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 1182] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Apr 29 17:04:53.599697 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1182] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Apr 29 17:04:53.605746 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 1182] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Apr 29 17:04:53.646755 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1182] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.2.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 29 17:04:53.646797 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1182] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

**The HTTP REQUEST LOGS do not contain new entries since the update.**

If I type hostname into SSH, it returns "server".

**ssl.conf** has the following 2 lines of interest:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

When I examine the certificate, I see CN=server

Cerbot installed its certificates in /etc/letsencrypt and they correspond to my 4 domain names.

My **hosts** file: (edited to hide my real domain names)

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost localhost4.localdomain4 localhost4
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
190.97.167.205 server.domain1.com  server domain2.com domain3.com domain4.monster
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

I don't think this is a firewall issue given that running links from the same box still produces the problem, but these entries from firewalld log don't look so good:

```
2020-04-29 16:48:18 WARNING: AllowZoneDrifting is enabled. This is considered an insecure configuration option. It will be removed in a future release. Please consider disabling it now.
2020-04-29 16:48:18 WARNING: ipset not usable, disabling ipset usage in firewall.
2020-04-29 16:48:20 WARNING: Failed to load nf_conntrack module: modprobe: ERROR: could not find module by name='nf_conntrack'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nf_conntrack': Function not implemented
modprobe: ERROR: Error running install command for nf_conntrack
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nf_conntrack': Operation not permitted

2020-04-29 16:48:20 ERROR: Failed to read file "/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper'
2020-04-29 16:48:20 WARNING: Failed to get and parse nf_conntrack_helper setting
2020-04-29 16:48:20 WARNING: ebtables not usable, disabling ethernet bridge firewall.
```

**What I have tried**

1. Rerunning certbot for all domains
2. Rerunning certbot for just domain1
3. Yum update (again) - no packages to install
4. Editing hosts file to remove server. and server - some system process restored it to original as above.
5. Commenting out the SSL entries for domain1 virtual host config and then going to http://... instead.
6. Commenting out the certificate lines in ssl.conf - apache wouldn't start, so I put them back.
7. Going to an HTML page instead of PHP - same result.

I'm starting to consider uninstall and reinstall, but I'm hoping maybe I'm just missing something here.  I would really appreciate help getting this fixed.

Thank you!

Comment: The firewalld errors might be because your VPS is preventing your system from loading kernel modules. Maybe it’s a OenVZ container?  What does `uname -r` return?

Comment: I don't think the VPS is preventing kernel modules because it worked fine until today. 
 I will say that I have had other odd problems with this particular installation.  It's CCI out of Panama.  uname -r returns 2.6.32-042stab142.1

Comment: I hate to tell you, but that’s an OpenVZ container. It will prevent you from loading certain modules, depending on the host kernel running your container. You can tell by the “stab” in the kernel version. Hosters use it because it lets them overprovision their hardware. No idea if it’s related to the httpd issues but it’s certainly an issue that’s breaking firewalld.

Comment: Judging from this ticket, make sure you’re running the firewalld in CentOS 7.8: https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/519

Comment: I tried running the firewalld downgrade as suggested by jsbillings.  I also tried a number of other things that I put in the top of my post.

Comment: OK the problem is firewalld.  I just stopped it and everything works. I don't know why I didn't think of that yesterday.  This server is sort of just a playground so I am somewhat inclined to just leave the firewall off, but I should probably get to the bottom of this and make it work right.  Thank you to JS Billings